# Class and attribute selector issues with IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a Jquery plugin called datetimepicker and works great in Firefox but not in IE8. I narrowed down the issue to be with the jquery selector. I have a table with a class named sm_whiteboard and in that table there's an input box with the ID Next_x0020_update_x0020_at (this ID dynamically changes which is what I did ID*).

```
    $("table.sm_whiteboard [id*=Next_x0020_update_x0020_at]").datetimepicker({
        addSliderAccess: true,
        sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false }
    });
```

This code works great in firefox but not in IE8. It doesn't give me any errors in the console in IE8. If I select only the input like this `$("[id*=Next_x0020_update_x0020_at]")` it works in IE8.

Any ideas where I could be going wrong?

Comment: Try to add tagname "table.sm_whiteboard input[id*=Next_x0020_update_x0020_at]" or use chain $("table.sm_whiteboard").find("[id*=Next_x0020_update_x0020_at]")

Comment: What do you get on IE8 for: `$("table.sm_whiteboard").length` ??? Check rendered HTML markup in IE8, maybe you are using invalid one, not parsed the same as on FF

Comment: @Jonathan in 2014, but still: http://www.kaspersky.com/about/news/virus/2014/16-37-per-cent-Users-Still-Run-Windows-XP-Kaspersky-Lab-Statistics-Say

Comment: Which is the full ID?

Comment: Assuming that an `ID` should be unique across the page, what's the problem on selecting the item straight by its `ID`? As you said, this way it works on IE8 anyway...

Comment: The full ID of the input is customEditInput_2_Next_x0020_update_x0020_at_10872 but its dynamic, so the last 5 characters will change randomly.

Comment: Which jQuery version?

Comment: @MelanciaUK Given the `*=` selector, this fragment may *not* uniquely identify an element on the page. Still, it would be helpful to see the actual HTML.

Comment: @Praveen im using jquery version 1.11.2.

Comment: @ A. Wolff when trying $("table.sm_whiteboard").length it returns 0 in IE8. I took a look at the markup as you suggested and noticed that there was capital letters in my class "SM_whiteboard" after changing that it started working. I wasent aware that IE8 was case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to A. Wolff I figured out that the problem was due to a simple character issue in my class name. Seems like IE8 is case sensitive so had to make sure the class name was matching exactly with all the capital letters as well.

Thanks everyone!

```
    $("table.SM_whiteboard [id*=Next_x0020_update_x0020_at]").datetimepicker({
        addSliderAccess: true,
        sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false }
    });
```